# Dynamically add checkboxes to ASP.NET web page using Javascript, tags are appearing incorrect

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am attempting to add checkboxes to a GridView when a field is being edited but it appears that the tags may be generated incorrectly. I am unable to create an input tag with a type of checkbox; I either end up with a "checkbox" tag or a select tag. The elements with a "checkbox" tag do not appear on my page.

Code that generates a "checkbox" tag:

```
// Check Box
let checkBoxElement = document.createElement("checkbox");
//checkBoxElement.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
checkBoxElement.setAttribute("name", FieldBeingEdited.attributes.title.value + "BOX");
checkBoxElement.setAttribute("value", option);
checkBoxElement.setAttribute("id", option);
checkBoxElement.setAttribute("width", "10px");
checkBoxElement.setAttribute("height", "10px");
if (CBcurrentValue.includes(option)) {
    checkBoxElement.setAttribute("checked", "true");
}
// Label for Check Box
let checkBoxLabel = document.createElement("label");
checkBoxLabel.setAttribute("for", option);
checkBoxLabel.innerHTML = option;
// Add both to the containing div
containerElement.appendChild(checkBoxElement);
containerElement.appendChild(checkBoxLabel);
containerElement.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
```

Resulting elements:

```
<checkbox name="CheckBoxSelectionBOX" value="Box 1" id="Box 1" width="10px" height="10px"></checkbox>
<label for="Box 1">Box 1</label>
<br>
```

Code that generates select tag:

```
// Check Box
let checkBoxElement = document.createElement("input");
checkBoxElement.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
checkBoxElement.setAttribute("name", FieldBeingEdited.attributes.title.value + "BOX");
checkBoxElement.setAttribute("value", option);
checkBoxElement.setAttribute("id", option);
checkBoxElement.setAttribute("width", "10px");
checkBoxElement.setAttribute("height", "10px");
if (CBcurrentValue.includes(option)) {
    checkBoxElement.setAttribute("checked", "true");
}
// Label for Check Box
let checkBoxLabel = document.createElement("label");
checkBoxLabel.setAttribute("for", option);
checkBoxLabel.innerHTML = option;
// Add both to the containing div
containerElement.appendChild(checkBoxElement);
containerElement.appendChild(checkBoxLabel);
containerElement.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
```

Resulting elements:

```
<select name="CheckBoxSelectionBOX" id="Box 1" width="10px" height="10px" step="1" size="2">
    <option value="True">True</option>
    <option value="False">False</option>
</select>
<label for="Box 1">Box 1</label>
<br>
```

I am debugging from Visual Studio 2019 on Chrome. I did try to run both pieces of code in Edge and got the same results.

Please let me know if I can provide any more information. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should create an `input` element, with attribute `type="checkbox"`.

Comment: @PeterB I tried to do that in the second code block, but instead of creating an `input` element it created a `select` element

Answer (score 0):

It turns out previous formatting in my Javascript was converting the `checkbox` elements into `number` input elements, then into true/false `select` elements. I was able to see this when I added a few `asp:checkbox` and `asp:checkboxlist` elements to the aspx file and they too were being converted.